# Implementation of .less files by browser

Tags: html, css, less

Suppose I use .less files for my CSS in my webpage . How is this .less parsed into CSS?
Is it parsed by browser ? 
If in case it is parsed by the browser
What will happen if browser does not support it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Less runs inside Node, in the browser and inside Rhino. There are also many 3rd party tools that allow you to compile your files and watch for changes.

*Source: [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/)*

It is possible to use Less in the browser. You can find instructions on how to do this in the the [Client Side Usage](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) section of the article. I copied some of the more pertinent text here. *Note that it is not recommended to use less.js in the browser for production.*

> > *Using less.js in the browser is great for development, but it's not recommended for production*
>
> Client-side is the easiest way to get started and good for developing with Less, but in production, when performance and reliability is important, we recommend pre-compiling using node.js or one of the many third party tools available.
>
> To start off, link your `.less` stylesheets with the `rel` attribute set to `stylesheet/less`:
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />`
>
> Next, download less.js and include it in a `<script></script>` tag in the `<head>` element of your page:
>
> `<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

*Source: [lesscss.org/#client-side-usage](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage)*